# How to fix return values not show up on one of my method

Tags: java

I tried to return values from two of my 4 methods so I can use print out on my final methods. The return value doesn't show up and my results were null and 0.0.

```
import java.util.*;
public class payroll {
    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    static double hour;
    static String employee; 
    static double rate;
    static double gross_pay;
    static double tax;
    static double deduction;
    static double net_pay;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            name();
            number(hour, rate, tax, gross_pay, deduction, net_pay);
            print();
    }
    public static String name() {
            System.out.print("Please enter employee's name: ");
            String employee = console.nextLine();

            return employee;

    }
    public static double[] number(double hour, double rate, double tax, double gross_pay, double deduction, double net_pay) {

            double[] pay = new double[7];
            pay[1] = hour;
            pay[2] = rate;
            pay[3] = tax;
            pay[4] = gross_pay;
            pay[5] = deduction;
            pay[6] = net_pay;

            System.out.print("Please enter number of hours worked: ");
            pay[1] = console.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("Please enter rate of pay: ");
            pay[2] = console.nextDouble();


            System.out.print("Please enter federal tax rate: ");
            pay[3] = console.nextDouble();

            pay[4]= hour*rate;
            pay[5] = gross_pay*tax;
            pay[6] = gross_pay-deduction;


            return pay;

    }
    public static void print() {
            System.out.printf("Employee's Name: " + employee + "\n" + 
                 "Hours Worked: " + hour + "\n" +
                 "Hourly Pay: " + rate + "\n" + 
                 "Gross Pay: " + gross_pay + "\n" +
                 "Tax Deducted: " + deduction + "\n" +
                 "Net Pay: " + net_pay);

    }
```

}

The expected results are the name of the employee and the calculations made in the methods.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are not assigning the return value to anything.

Normally you would do something like

```
employee = name();
```

But other points to mention is that you have `employee` etc declared as fields, so they are directly accessible via the methods

e.g.

```
public static void name() {  // do not return any thing
        System.out.print("Please enter employee's name: ");

        // do not de-declare, just use the field
        employee = console.nextLine();

}
```

This would be correct to use, as you are not passing any parameters to `print` and are printing out the values of the fields

Comment: Oh wow, it works. I really over complicated myself. Thank you so much!